# Implementing CSS in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to implement a simple CSS file to my python web app. When I try loding the app, I get a error message in the command prompt that says:

```
"GET /static/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1658
```

And of course no CSS is implemented to the HTML page. The structure of my Project is:

```
ProjectName
 MyApp
 MyTeachingApp
  static
   css
    default.css
 templates
  page.html
```

In my `settings.py`, I got:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And in the html I got the link tag inside the head like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/default.css" %}" />
```

How do I correctly implement the CSS in my web app? Do I've to add something to the `url.py`? Or is it in the settings.py using the `STATIC_ROOT` or `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

I'm using Django 1.9.

My `urls.py` file contains the following code:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^caesarTemp/', include('TeachingTool.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is the `urls.py` inside the `MyApp` folder.

I have an extra `urls.py` file inside a `MyTeachingApp` folder that contains:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.printAlphabet, name = 'print'),
]
```

I tried adding the static statement to this `urls.py` file and still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple. Also, add the `urlpatterns` for serving static files with your local development server, like mastazi said:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Your app is named `MyTeachingApp` so it seems; your `INSTALLED APPS` configuration should look like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'MyTeachingApp',
]
```

Comment: What do I have to add to the INSTALLED_APPS? Like django.contrib.MyApp?

Comment: If your python chdir is directory of the root of your app, then just add 'MyTeachingApp'

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally it worked, I was missing adding the app to the settings.py

Comment: @Silvestrini yes of course Dmitri is absolutely right, I didn't realise that MyTeachingApp wasn't in your INTALLED_APPS list, sorry for having missed that!

Answer (score 1):

If you have static files that are associated to one specific app, the structure would be:

```
Project
    MyApp
        static
            MyApp
                css
                js

                etc...
```

So inside static you should have a subfolder named as the app.
The reason is explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in my_app/static/ (rather than creating another my_app subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.

**EDIT:**
Also make sure that you have configured your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I tried what you said here of putting the static files in the MyApp folder and creating a subfolder with the same name and also added to the urls.py the static statement and yet it still won't detect the css files. Got any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try to put a file in Project/static/ (i.e. not in the app) and then try to see if it's loaded... Also it would be good if you could share your urls.py, for example do you have only one urls.py for the whole project or you also have one urls.py for each app?.

Comment: I edited the post, see what I added about both the urls.py files I have. I also tried putting the static folder inside the Project folder and it didn't find it.